# How to print the SOAP request?

Tags: php, api, debugging, soap

I'm trying to send a SOAP request but I receive an error telling me that some parameters are invalid. Here's the code:

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://live.domainbox.net/?WSDL', array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
$params = array(
    'AuthenticationParameters' => array(
        'Reseller' => 'reseller',
        'Username' => 'username',
        'Password' => 'password'
    ),
    'CommandParameters' => array(
        'DomainName' => 'mydomain.com',
        'LaunchPhase' => 'GA'
    )
);

$result = $client->CheckDomainAvailability($params);
print_r($result);
```

Here's the error message:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [CheckDomainAvailabilityResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ResultCode] => 201
            [ResultMsg] => Authentication Failed: Invalid Authentication Parameters
            [TxID] => xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
            [AvailabilityStatus] => 3
            [AvailabilityStatusDescr] => ErrorOccurred
            [LaunchPhase] => GA
            [DropDate] => 
            [BackOrderAvailable] => 
        )

)
```

I want to see the request sent to the server to make sure it's well formated.

Here's how it need to be formated:

```
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance”
xmlns:xsd=”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema” xmlns:soap12=”http://www.w3.org/2003/05/
soap-envelope”>
<soap12:Body>
    <CheckDomainAvailability xmlns=”https://live.domainbox.net/”>
        <AuthenticationParameters>
            <Reseller>myreseller</Reseller>
            <Username>myuser</Username>
            <Password>mypassword</Password>
        </AuthenticationParameters>
        <CommandParameters>
            <DomainName>checkadomain.co</DomainName>
            <LaunchPhase>GA</LaunchPhase>
        </CommandParameters>
    </CheckDomainAvailability>
</soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

How can I print the request that has been sent to the server?

I already tried:

```
echo $client->__getLastRequest();
```

But I got nothing, even in the source code of the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add tracing option:

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://live.domainbox.net/?WSDL', array('trace' => true, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
```

Then `__getLastRequest()` should work.